GoogleCloud Networking BYOIP with part of subnet advertised from on-site via VPN tunnel
I have a public IP subnet that I currently use onsite for our public facing servers and I would like to take them step-by-step to google cloud using their BYOIP support.
For testing I brought one subnet to google and currently advertisement is working and when IPs are assigned to VM instance it is accessible through the internet from my subnet.
My wish is that I would like to announce the subnet (i.e. 1.1.1.1/24) from google cloud, use part of it on VM instances and services in google cloud and a part of it (i.e. 1.1.1.240/28) to be still used from on-site servers.
I have established a tunnel between GC and my site and also BGP sessions for dynamic routing, and while the advertised route from my site is accessible from inside GC services the IPs are not accessible from internet.
Also tried creating a CloudRouter and an CR Instance which advertises it's own part of subnet (i.e. 1.1.1.224/28) which again the IPs from this advertised subnet is accessible from inside GC but not from public which I would like to achieve.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Google does not support overlapping BYOIP route announcements. For example, importing 203.0.112.0/23 is not supported if 203.0.112.0/23 or a subset of this prefix, such as 203.0.112.0/24, is advertised outside Google.
If Google and another network advertise the same route with matching or mismatched prefix lengths, you might experience unexpected routing and packet loss.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/bring-your-own-ip

Maybe I did not explain good enough; I know that google does not support overlapping announcements, that is why I announce the whole /24 from google cloud and I would like to use it for IP transit for the sub-allocation (/28) to server on-site.
